# running ndk-stack on arm64-v8a lib fail with error File format not recognized

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk, arm64

I created native based prebuilt lib for `arm64-v8a`. I have crash in run time and I like to run `ndk-stack` on the crash log (just like I did for `armeabi-v7a` lib), but now the `ndk-stack` return error message

> File format not recognized

And fail to show the back trace.
What is the correct way to run `ndk-stack` for `arm64-v8a` file?
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Note that, for the `-sym` option `-sym $PROJECT_PATH/obj/local/armeabi-v7a`, you need to specify your symbol file correctly, e.g. matching the ABI properly, for `arm64-v8a`, it should be something like `-sym $PROJECT_PATH/obj/local/arm64-v8a`

**See the official usage document here:** https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack

> There are two ways to use the tool. You can feed the logcat text as direct input to the program. For example:
>
> ```
> adb logcat | $NDK/ndk-stack -sym $PROJECT_PATH/obj/local/armeabi-v7a
> ```
>
> You can also use the -dump option to specify the logcat as an input file. For example:
>
> ```
> adb logcat > /tmp/foo.txt $NDK/ndk-stack -sym $PROJECT_PATH/obj/local/armeabi-v7a -dump foo.txt
> ```
>
> When it begins parsing the logcat output, the tool looks for an initial line of asterisks. For example:
>
> `*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***`